# stuck thread in createQueueConnection

Tags: jms, ejb, weblogic

I am getting the stuck thread error often while trying to send the JMS message to another manager server within the domain in our production environment. 
Initially, we felt that it might be due to Load on the server but issue occurred randomly Even at the time of less load and system processing well some  high volume time

We are not able to find the reason for the same.

Error Information:

> weblogic.jms.client.JMSConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(JMSConnectionFact
>   ory.java:199)

Comment: weblogic.jms.client.JMSConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:199)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).